# How to give textinput skin to the textinput control in flex 4.5 mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have created a class RoundedTextInputSkin that extends from TextInputSkin

```
    package skins
{

    import assets.TextInput_389X35;

    import spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin;

    public class RoundedTextInputSkin extends TextInputSkin
    {

        public function RoundedTextInputSkin()
        {
            super();
            borderClass =  TextInput_389X35;
            layoutBorderSize = 5;
        } 
    }
}
```

Now i have given this skin as skinClass to the textInput Control. I could able to see the roundedTextInput but text entered in the textinput is not visible.
Can any one please tell me what went wrong with my code.

Here is my fxg file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Graphic version="2.0" ai:appVersion="16.0.0.682" ATE:version="1.0.0" flm:version="1.0.0" d:using="" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008" xmlns:ATE="http://ns.adobe.com/ate/2009" xmlns:ai="http://ns.adobe.com/ai/2009" xmlns:d="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008/dt" xmlns:flm="http://ns.adobe.com/flame/2008">
      <Group x="3" y="1.35449" ai:seqID="1" flm:knockout="false">
        <Rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="389" height="35" radiusX="16.9997" radiusY="16.9997" ai:seqID="2">
          <fill>
            <LinearGradient x="194.5" y="0.38916" scaleX="34.2022" rotation="90">
              <GradientEntry ratio="0" color="#B0B0B0"/>
              <GradientEntry ratio="1" color="#E0E0E0"/>
            </LinearGradient>
          </fill>
        </Rect>
        <Rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="389" height="35" radiusX="16.9997" radiusY="16.9997" ai:seqID="3"/>
      </Group>
</Graphic>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT is not clear how your FXG file relates to the skin class you showed.  But, I'm going to assume that the FXG you provided is the TextInput_389X35 referenced in code.  I assume that your custom border is on top of all other elements; making them invisible.  Per the createChildren() method of TextSkinBase; the border element is placed on top of everything else:

```
override protected function createChildren():void
{
 super.createChildren();
 if (!textDisplay)
 {
     textDisplay = StyleableTextField(createInFontContext(StyleableTextField));
     textDisplay.styleName = this;
     textDisplay.editable = true;
     textDisplay.useTightTextBounds = false;
     addChild(textDisplay);
 }

 if (!border)
 {
   border = new borderClass();
   addChild(border);
 }
}
```

The default Border FXG elements use paths to create the border so that the "fill" is a border.  By using a Rectangle, you are placing a big square on top of everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the comment flextras. I tried by putting your code adding createChildren but still i am unable to see the text entered in the textinput. I have given borderClass to borderClass =  TextInput_389X35; Where TextInpu_389X35 is fxg.

Comment: @Trinu That isn't my code; it is copied directly from TextSkinBase in order to show that the BorderClass is added last; thus covering up everything else.  If you want to override createChildren() so that the borderclass is put on the bottom; you can do that.  But, I think you'll be better suited re-working your FXG to use a path instead of a rectangle.

Comment: @Flextras how to use path instead of rectangle i tried in adobe illustrator it is always giving me a rectangle but not path.Can you please help me in this. I am unable to see the text in the textinput.

Comment: I can't help because I don't know the shape you want.

Comment: The shape is exactly what i have given in the above fxg which i have posted.

Comment: You have two rectangle fills that cover up the rest of your TextInput; if that was what you wanted you probably wouldn't have needed to post a question.

Comment: When i use the rectangle i am unable to see the text entered in the textinput thats the problem i have faced and i have posted here.

Comment: As I said "The default Border FXG elements use paths to create the border so that the "fill" is a border." You need to create a path in the shape you need that does not fill a full rectangle.  I cannot help you create that path.